# How to rotate 2D UIElement around a 3D axis (Y)?

Tags: wpf

I have a `Grid` with some content (image, text) and I would like to rotate it around y-axis in 3D space - somehow an animated tilt effect.

Is there an easy way like Rotate3DTransform directly applicable to the `Grid`?

Comment: I have some experience on such transformations. I would like to see your expected output before I can answer your question.

Comment: It looks a bit like an opened door with perspective distortion - a page tilt effect like this: http://www.simpleviewer.net/tiltviewer/ although I don't need an arbitrary axis. The page to be tilt would contain some UIElement (containing others). For me, the 3D model is not the problem, but instead how to place any 2D content on it. Something like Josh Smiths ContentControl3D, which however flips 180deg. In the meantime I found "WPF Tilt Shader Effect" which helped so far, but the question whether it's possible to rotate 2D UIElements in 3D remains.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Using Viewport3D**

[image: 3D rotate]

if you are willing to use 3D models and rotations then here is a sample I attempted to for you, I tried to reproduce the expected result, may not be accurate

```
    <Viewport3D>
        <Viewport3D.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="Image">
                <Setter Property="Width"
                        Value="20" />
                <Setter Property="Margin"
                        Value="4" />
                <Setter Property="Source"
                        Value="desert.jpg" />
                <Setter Property="Effect">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="4"
                                          Direction="0"
                                          ShadowDepth="0" />
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </Viewport3D.Resources>
        <Viewport3D.Camera>
            <PerspectiveCamera Position="0, 0, 4" />
        </Viewport3D.Camera>
        <Viewport2DVisual3D>
            <Viewport2DVisual3D.Transform>
                <RotateTransform3D>
                    <RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
                        <QuaternionRotation3D x:Name="rotate"
                                              Quaternion="0, 0, 0, 0.5" />
                    </RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
                </RotateTransform3D>
            </Viewport2DVisual3D.Transform>
            <Viewport2DVisual3D.Geometry>
                <MeshGeometry3D Positions="-1,1,0 -1,-1,0 1,-1,0 1,1,0"
                                TextureCoordinates="0,0 0,1 1,1 1,0"
                                TriangleIndices="0 1 2 0 2 3" />
            </Viewport2DVisual3D.Geometry>
            <Viewport2DVisual3D.Material>
                <DiffuseMaterial Viewport2DVisual3D.IsVisualHostMaterial="True" />
            </Viewport2DVisual3D.Material>
            <UniformGrid Columns="3"> <!--host your content here-->
                <Image />
                <Image />
                <Image />
                <Image />
                <Image />
                <Image />
                <Image />
                <Image />
                <Image />
            </UniformGrid>
        </Viewport2DVisual3D>
        <ModelVisual3D>
            <ModelVisual3D.Content>
                <DirectionalLight Color="#FFFFFFFF"
                                  Direction="0,0,-1" />
            </ModelVisual3D.Content>
        </ModelVisual3D>
        <Viewport3D.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Viewport3D.Loaded">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <QuaternionAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="rotate"
                                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="Quaternion"
                                             To="-0.25, 0.25, 0.15, 0.65"
                                             Duration="0:0:10"
                                             RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                            <QuaternionAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                <ElasticEase />
                            </QuaternionAnimation.EasingFunction>
                        </QuaternionAnimation>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Viewport3D.Triggers>
    </Viewport3D>
```

now you can rotate your model which is the UI host, currently hosting the grid with the image tiles.

also you can convert same to a style & template for ContentControl with attached properties for rotation and reuse it where you want.

**Using 2D transforms**

a sample for you to achieve 3D transform into grid with normal transformations

[image: 3D rotate via 2D transform]

the key is to convert 3D transform to 2D and apply to grid directly without complex 3D stuff (this sample does not have any converstion) it simply demonstrate a 3D looking grid transformation for your reference.

```
    <Grid Width="100" Height="100" >
        <Grid.Background>
            <ImageBrush Opacity=".5" ImageSource="Desert.jpg"/>
        </Grid.Background>
        <Button Content="Some Text" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        <Grid.RenderTransform>
            <SkewTransform x:Name="skew" CenterX="50" CenterY="50"/>
        </Grid.RenderTransform>
        <Grid.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="skew" Duration="0:0:25" Storyboard.TargetProperty="AngleX" From="0" To="60" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                            <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                <ElasticEase/>
                            </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                        </DoubleAnimation>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="skew" Duration="0:0:20" Storyboard.TargetProperty="AngleY" From="0" To="50" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                            <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                <ElasticEase/>
                            </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                        </DoubleAnimation>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Grid.Triggers>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: Yes, I started with SkewTransformation, but I wasn't able to change it deterministically to look like a more or less tilt page.

Comment: Since you are willing to go for 3D, I updated my answer for the same. Now you will have full control over rotation using Viewport3D

Comment: Yep this is the host for your UI elements in 3D space.