# Use a VisualBrush in Viewport in UserControl WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to use a VisualBrush in a Viewport3D in UserControl, when I'm in the Blend for Visual Studio environment everything is fine and it shows! but when I debug the project it wont appear at all!

I Have 2 grids (as pages) and 1 Viewport3D object in UserControl, I want that when I click on Forward button, Viewport3D flip the page1 to page2, It works fine in Window, but I can't use it in UserControl, I mean it wont appear.

Please guide me if you can.

Link to UserControl.cs -> [Click Here](http://ir-developer.com/dl/UserControl.cs)

Comment: I've tried everything i could, but I didn't get any result.

Comment: here is one of my previous answer for solving the similar problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24223313/how-to-rotate-2d-uielement-around-a-3d-axis-y/24227220#24227220

Comment: Thanks but it's not what I mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are just looking forward to see the visual brush as diffuse material

here you go

```
<Grid>
    <Grid x:Name="Page1_Grid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="210" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="216" Visibility="Hidden">
        <Grid x:Name="Page1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="210" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="216">
            <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="190" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="196" Margin="10,10,0,0" CornerRadius="5" Background="#FFFF9B9B" RenderTransformOrigin="-0.041,0.411">
                <Button x:Name="button" Content="Forward" Margin="9,19,99,130" Click="Button_Click"/>
            </Border>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
    <Grid x:Name="Page2_Grid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="210" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="216" Visibility="Hidden" d:IsHidden="True">
        <Grid x:Name="Page2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="210" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="216">
            <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="190" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="196" Margin="10,10,0,0" CornerRadius="5" Background="#FFFF9B9B" RenderTransformOrigin="-0.041,0.411">
                <Button Content="Back" Margin="9,19,99,130"/>
            </Border>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
    <Viewport3D HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="190" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="196" Margin="10,10,0,0">
        <Viewport3D.Camera>
```

I have moved the grid containing the visuals for the brush before the viewport so it can be ready before the diffuse material can pick up.