# Rotate canvas along x axis in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a 2D canvas that I want to rotate along the x-axis. I later want to animate movement of the object along the z-axis.

With CSS, rotating along the x-axis is straightforward:
`transform: rotateX(30deg);`, and so is translation over the z-axis.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/33t0ov24/) is a demonstration of how I want to rotate the XAML canvas.

How can I achieve the same effect in XAML/WPF? I tried using a `Viewport3D` with a `Viewport2DVisual3D` as a starting point to apply the 3D transformation. However, the canvas does not even render once placed. I don't know if the material lighting or geometry needs to be adjusted. What's the best approach I should go for? Is there a tool I can use to simplify this work?

I tried using code from [How to rotate 2D UIElement around a 3D axis (Y)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24223313/how-to-rotate-2d-uielement-around-a-3d-axis-y), and [How to rotate 2D UIElement around a 3D axis (Y)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24223313/how-to-rotate-2d-uielement-around-a-3d-axis-y). I can't seem to get my code to work with a canvas.

EDIT:

I tried using the code at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34391/Rotating-WPF-Content-in-D-Space (section "ContentControl3D Internals") as a base for the starting point:

```
<Viewport2DVisual3D>
  <Viewport2DVisual3D.Geometry>
    <MeshGeometry3D TriangleIndices="0,1,2 2,3,0" TextureCoordinates="0,1 1,1 1,0 0,0" Positions="-1,-1,0 1,-1,0 1,1,0 -1,1,0" />
  </Viewport2DVisual3D.Geometry>
  <Viewport2DVisual3D.Transform>
    <RotateTransform3D>
     <RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
        <AxisAngleRotation3D Angle="180" />
     </RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
    </RotateTransform3D>
  </Viewport2DVisual3D.Transform>
  <Viewport2DVisual3D.Material>
    <DiffuseMaterial Viewport2DVisual3D.IsVisualHostMaterial="True" Brush="White" />
  </Viewport2DVisual3D.Material>
  <Viewport2DVisual3D.Visual>
    <Border BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="1">
      <Canvas>
        <!-- ... -->
      </Canvas>
    </Border>
   </Viewport2DVisual3D.Visual>
</Viewport2DVisual3D>
```

The canvas does not render. I did try using other wrappers as well from the other links I provided, and had no luck getting the visuals to render.

Comment: What kind of Effect are you trying to achieve (Sample pictures)? This sounds like it could be easily done with `RenderTransform`.

Comment: Also show some code please

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer I added a demonstration of how I want to rotate it https://jsfiddle.net/33t0ov24/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From this example page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appid=dev14idef1&l=en-us&k=k(system.windows.media.media3d.viewport2dvisual3d);k(vs.xamleditor);k(targetframeworkmoniker-.netframework,version%3dv4.6)&rd=true#Anchor_8), Add a camera and some lighting (lighting optional):

```
<Viewport3D>
    <Viewport3D.Camera>
        <PerspectiveCamera Position="0, 0, 4"/>
    </Viewport3D.Camera>

    <ModelVisual3D>
        <ModelVisual3D.Content>
            <DirectionalLight Color="#FFFFFFFF" Direction="0,0,-1"></DirectionalLight>
        </ModelVisual3D.Content>
    </ModelVisual3D>

    <Viewport2DVisual3D>
    ...
    </Viewport2DVisual3D>
```

The rotation angle 180 is really big, I think that is flipping your border all the way around backwards.

Comment: Lighting is optional. But Axis seems important `<AxisAngleRotation3D Axis="1,0,0" Angle="-80" />`

Comment: yes the 180 degree angle is very big too, more than 90 makes it show the back, right?